# NPM Ng Build --Prod fails in build process Azure DevOps Everytime

Tags: npm, continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

My build will not finish because it fails on the NPM step of Ng Build

Here is the build process and error:

1. `npm install -g @angular/cli`
2. `npm install`
3. `ng build` (or `ng build --prod`) depending on your preference
4. Publish Artifacts

On step 3, I get the Error: Npm failed with return code: 1

Details around user-agent = "npm/6.5.0 node/v10.15.0 win32 x64"

My package.json file exists in the repository and I've tried having it look specifically in that file or in the directory.

It seems to fail on this line of cold in the build on step 3 "command]C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C "C:\npm\prefix\npm.cmd ng build""

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i prefer to use docker nodejs containers to build node files on azure devops

Comment: @Shayki, If you have the build steps, I'd gladly give it a go at this point.

Comment: @jepple33 try to run the build with `debug=true`